How to create mechanical arms with joints and resistance
I want to create a mechanical arm with several sections connected by joints. Think exoskeleton kind of.
This arm will have a handle at one end and the user holds onto this handle with their hand.
Now the user when they pull the handle, the arm will move is a predefined path, a kind of bulb shape path. The goal is for the users arm to move in a specific path(bulb shape). To make things even more complex, the arm should apply resistance relative to the strength the user is pulling on the mechanical arm.
Is this too complex of a device to build?

Not sure what you mean by "bulb shaped path." A bulb is three dimensional, a path is one dimensional.  Do you mean something like a helix where the radius increases, but then decreases?

I meant a half bulb shape.
